# How to generate random grey colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have a function and would like to generate only grey colors. How can I do this with the code below? I'm pretty new to javascript! I'd appreciate any help. I'm using Paper.js

```
 function onMouseDown(event) {
        path = new Path();
        path.fillColor = {
            hue: Math.random() * 360,
            //saturation: 0,
            //brightness: 0.5
        };

        path.add(event.point);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a library of some sort. I don't recognise it. Could be Paper.js? Perhaps it's your own. Can you let us know what it is please? If it's Paper.js you can feed it a hex colour rather than the HSL separates in your example. See: http://paperjs.org/reference/color/

Comment: @Moob I'm indeed using paper.js!  Thank you for your response. I should have clarified that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the example you provide accepts HSB colours you can simply generate a random brightness value. The saturation should be 0 (fully desaturated) and the hue can also be 0 as it is redundant.

The Brightness value should be a number between 0 an 1. Since you want grey specifically you may want to get a value back that's neither too dark or too light. We can make a little method to return a random number between two values.

```
function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

So in you code you would use it like this:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    path = new Path();
    path.fillColor = {
        hue: 0, 
        saturation: 0,
        brightness: getRandomInRange(0.2, 0.8)
    };

    path.add(event.point);
}
```

**Update**

Paper.js has a [Color constructor specifically for greyscale](http://paperjs.org/reference/color/#color-gray) that would also be appropriate to use here. It takes a number from 0 - 1 (where 0 is black) so the `getRandomInRange` will work equally well here:

```
path.fillColor = new Color(getRandomInRange(0.2, 0.8)); //a random grey
```

Comment: Not sure about the library you're using but `getRandomInRange(0,100)` could be used if it's expecting a percentage.

Comment: Thanks @Moob ! This worked perfectly. You are awesome.

Answer (score 9):

Since grey colours have equal RGB components you can generate a hex in the range 0 - ff and use it for each of the R,G,B parts:

```js
function randomGreyHex() {
  var v = (Math.random()*(256)|0).toString(16);//bitwise OR. Gives value in the range 0-255 which is then converted to base 16 (hex).
  return "#" + v + v + v;
}

/* demo usage: */
var div = document.querySelector("div");
div.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var grey = randomGreyHex();
  this.style.backgroundColor = grey;
  this.innerHTML = grey;
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">click me</div>
```

Comment: Well, I see you beat me to it! :-) In case OP has an interest in using RGB then I made an example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53rqxtp4/5/) in which there is some slight variations to the colors and limited to some of the midrange-tones (not 100% black and not 100% white). However, would you mind explaining exactly what the `(255)|0)` part does? I see that it's working as intended, returning numbers between 0 and 255, and it's an awesome method, I just haven't seen it before and I'm wondering about the technicality behind it?

Comment: @Chri.s It’s a [Bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29) and effectively truncates the random number at the decimal point (so is the same as Math.floor in that sense).

Comment: @Chri.s Your comment made me re-evaluate my code.. Since `Math.random()` returns a number from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive) it was clear that  `Math.random()*255` could _never actually be 255_ so I've updated it to 256 so when floored the max will be 255 (ff). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [randomColor](https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor) library.

To generate a random grey colour it would be:

```
randomColor({hue: 'monochrome', count: 1});
```

This, however, would include black too. You can use the luminosity key set to "light" to only get real grey colours.

```
randomColor({hue: 'monochrome',luminosity: 'light', count: 1});
```

A small demo, emulating the coloured balls we find on the GitHub repo:

```js
var colours = randomColor({
  hue: 'monochrome',
  count: 5,
  luminosity: 'light'
});

var myDiv = document.getElementById('squares');

colours.forEach(function(colour) {
  myDiv.innerHTML += `<span class="circle" style="color:${colour}"></span>`
});
```

```css
.circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.min.js"></script>


<div id="squares">

</div>
```